# Не могу добавить данные только в одну колонку, помогите, пожалуйста. MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, swing

Суть проблемы: я пишу код, который добавляет в mysql данные пользователя и данные о счете Змейки. Я не могу написать метод для БД, который бы добавлял данные, для ОДНОГО параметра, в отдельный столбец.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DatabaseHandler extends Configs {
    Connection dbConnection;

    public DatabaseHandler() {
    }

    public Connection getDbConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        String connectionString = "jdbc:mysql://" + this.dbHost + ":" + this.dbPort + "/" + this.dbName;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        this.dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, this.dbUser, this.dbPass);
        return this.dbConnection;
    }

    public void signUpUser(String name, String number, String game_score) {
        String insert = "INSERT users1(name,number,game_score)VALUES(?,?,?)";

        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = this.getDbConnection().prepareStatement(insert);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, name);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, number);
            preparedStatement.setString(3, game_score);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException var5) {
            throw new RuntimeException(var5);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException var6) {
            throw new RuntimeException(var6);
        }
    }

    public void signUpScore(String game_score) {
        String insert = "INSERT users1(game_score)VALUES(?)";
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = this.getDbConnection().prepareStatement(insert);
            preparedStatement.setString(3, game_score);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException var5) {
            throw new RuntimeException(var5);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException var6) {
            throw new RuntimeException(var6);
        }
    }

}
```

И вот как последовательно добавляю данные:

```
String r = "не заполнено";
DatabaseHandler databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler();
databaseHandler.signUpUser(r, r, r);
databaseHandler.signUpUser(CONT.this.name_field.getText(), CONT.this.number_field.getText(), r);

 for(int i = 0; GameField.this.dots >= 3; ++i) {
                    if (GameField.this.dots < 36) {
                        textArea[0] = new JTextArea(String.valueOf(i));
                        DatabaseHandler databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler();
                        databaseHandler.signUpScore(String.valueOf(i));
                    }
                }
```

Выводится ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я не заполню game_score как r, то будет необходим третий параметр.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у вас в последнем примере цикл либо работает бесконечно, либо не отрабатывает вовсе  `for(int i = 0; GameField.this.dots >= 3; ++i)` так как тут в условии “i” не проверяется, а параметр который указан  не изменяется в теле цикла, проверьте этот момент дописав в тело цикла вначале например простое System.out.println(“цикл “ + i);

обновлено:
только сейчас заметил:)  preparedStatement.setString(3, game_score);  у тебя тут цифра 3, а в параметрах только 1, соответственно ты пытаешся указать что третье значение такое, а значений только одно, поменяй на 1 в методе signUpScore, цифра в том параметре, указывает на порядковый номер знака вопроса

Comment: dots изменяется ранее. Как тело змейки, она увеличивается на 1 при столкновении с яблоком. Здесь вопрос скорее в том, как я могу добавить данные в столбец, из другого класса, не добавляя параметр в первый метод

Comment: Все работает как надо, когда я удаляю добавление в базу данных. Но как только добавляю, то пишет, что не хватает параметров и переменных в signUpScore

Comment: А какой запрос итого формируется для отправки в БД, можешь сюда скинуть? Выведи его перед самой отправкой

Comment: Или поставь метки под дебаг почти на каждый шаг, и проверь на каком моменте у тебя теряются значения к запросу к БД

Comment: INSERT users1(name, number, game_score) 
VALUES ('name', 'number', 'game_score');

И дальше так пытаюсь:

INSERT users1(game_score) 
VALUES ('game_score');

Comment: это структура которую задумал или конкретный вывод перед отправкой? Я кстати не до конца понял суть вопроса, ты случайно не пытаешся добавить уже в существующую строку значение? Если да то запрос надо начинать не с insert, а с update, а в конце добавить условие where name=‘name’ дабы сказать в какой именно строке поменять, лучше это даже по id сделать, гоавное чтобы уникальное значение было и не зацепить лишние строки

Comment: если всё-таки пытаешся добавить просто строку с одним значением, то проверь в БД не стоят ли остальные поля как обязательные к заполнению, или в запросе формируя добавь null тем значениям которые не хочешь заполнять

Comment: только сейчас заметил:)  preparedStatement.setString(3, game_score);  у тебя тут цифра 3, а в параметрах только 1, соответственно ты пытаешся указать что третье значение такое, а значений только одно, поменяй на 1 в методе signUpScore, цифра в том параметре, указывает на порядковый номер знака вопроса

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!!! Тяжело искать информацию по этой теме

Comment: Ошибка осталась та же...хотя если просто написать запрос с любым значением вместо game_score, то все работает....  `public void signUpScore(String game_score) { String insert = "UPDATE users1 /n" + "SET game_score = " + game_score + "/n" + "WHERE game_score = null" + ";"; try { PreparedStatement preparedStatement = this.getDbConnection().prepareStatement(insert); preparedStatement.setString(1, game_score); preparedStatement.executeUpdate(); } catch (SQLException var5) { throw new RuntimeException(var5);`

Comment: попробуй еще в месте где в запросе "SET game_score = " + game_score + "/n"
добавить кавычки одинарные типа чтобы вышло так  "SET game_score = '" + game_score + "'/n"

Comment: Спасибо! Решил проблему, когда убрал NN в таблице MySQL со всех значений. Появилась проблема с добавлением счёта - он всегда null.